# How to get an excel file uploaded in MVC controller

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to upload an excel file . I am using AngularJS + MVC. The view is an html file and the file upload is simple html file upload. After uploading the file , when i click a button, i must be able to access the excel file in the MVC controller.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetFile(HttpPostedFileBase file) 
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0) 
        {
            //do stuff here
        }         
    }
```

Comment: I may be wrong. But since there is no page submission,but routing will the HttpPostedFileBase class contain anything???

Comment: @user3851706 how are you submitting to the controller ? Because if you want to access the file you must be posting it somehow.

Comment: Am new to both technologies. But looking at the other pages, they are routing rather than redirecting as in conventional aspx pages.

Comment: $scope.saveProfile = function (profile) {
        dataService.asyncPost("/api/ControllerName/", profile).then(function (data) {
            if ($scope.uploader.queue.length > 0) {
                if (($scope.uploader.queue[0].file.size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) < 3) {
                    $scope.uploader.queue[0].upload();
                } else {
                    alert('Upload failed, please select the image less than 3MB size');
                    profile.InEditMode = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
        profile.InEditMode = false;}

Comment: @user3851706 To submit a file you shouldn`t route. The routing will execute an HttpGet and you will need HttpPost to recieve the file in the controller.

Comment: Hi as mentioned in the above code its using dataService.asyncPost

Comment: @user3851706 have you tried adding the method I posted in your controller and testing if it works ? I am not very good at angular.js but if it is doing a normal post - the method should be able to handle it.

Comment: Will try and let you know